# I often get this update error. Don't understand what it is

Tags: 20.04, package-management, upgrade, updates, dependencies

[image]

Ubuntu 20.04. I have 2 PCs and I often get this error on both of them. After a while that notification disappeares.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: Please [edit] and add the output of `sudo apt update` also provide the output of `sudo apt-get upgrade` . If you wana know how to ask a good question then you can refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)